# how to get item from SelectList in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

i'm creating a custom registration form for only use by admin of the site in this registration form the admin can add user and give them role in the site so i make this Model for define the from

```
public class AddUserToRoleModels
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Select Role")]
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and make this method in class Function to add user and give them role

```
public class Functions
{
    public void AddUserToRole(string UserName,string PassWord,string Role) {

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(UserName))
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(UserName, PassWord);

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName).Contains(Role))
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { UserName }, new[] { Role });
    }
}
```

then i create this controller

```
public class AddUserToRoleController : Controller
{
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AddUserToRoleModels model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Functions ob = new Functions();

            ob.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Roles);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName");
            return View(model);

    }
 }
```

and create the view for the create action controller

```
@model SeniorProject.Models.AddUserToRoleModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

 <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>AddUserToRoleModels</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("RoleId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

  }

<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

 @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

when i try to add new user and give him role the user insert to the database but without role and i think because that i'm trying to get the role from the `@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", String.Empty)` and it is list and my method it take string parameter for role and i try to take the selected item from this list but no working ether so please help...

Comment: you need to bind the RoleID to an int field. In Ryan's answer, the dropdownlist value will bind to the model property `int RoleID`

Comment: The way your code is written, if you added `int RoleId` to the parameter list of your Create method it will bind to that.

Comment: role id is not posted with model in the create httppost action?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, ViewBag.RoleID, "")
```

or something similar to that.

And you can also put the list in your viewmodel as a selectList and then just call it as Model.RoleIDs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleName");
    return View();
}
```

In view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, ViewBag.Roles as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select a role" )
```

In Post action `if(model.RoleId == 0)`, so you don't select any role.

Answer (score -1):

in controller

```
using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext()){
    var tmp = db.Roles.ToList();
    ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(tmp, "RoleId", "RoleName");
}
```

in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, (SelectList)@ViewBag.RoleId)
```